# Last tab/window of domain in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

**Question: Is** there a function or way for a tab in IE to know that it is the last tab of this domain/subdomain?

**Details:**

We got an internal messaging system which is ancient monster thus it only runs on IE7 (can be ran on IE10/11 with IE7 compatible mode), i will refer this system as monster. 
The monster is built in .net and now we have a newer system which is built with PHP, lets call it baby.

They got different sub-domains but they are on the same domain. (monster.somedomain.com and baby.somedomain.com)

The requirement is whenever someone logs into monster, we need to log them in into baby and whenever they log out/close off all the monster windows/tabs, we need to log them out of baby.

What i almost need is a way to know when a user closes a tab, is this the last monster tab, if it is, we need to log this user out of baby.

I have tried `window.onunload` and make use of `localstorage` but it seems that `window.onunload` doesn't work very well when too many iframes floating around.

Comment: maby `window.onbeforeunload`  can help you

Comment: well explained!